# Como restar valores en diccionarios Python

Tags: python, diccionarios, calculo

Tengo un controle de deudas que están guardadas por nombre y valores respectivos de cada uno en un diccionario. Quería una ayuda para saberlo como hago las restas de un valor dentro del diccionario.

```
deudas = dict()
deudas['Nombre de la persona'] = float(input('Digite o valor devedor a  "Fafa":€ valor deuda' ))
print(deudas)

float(input('Ingrese el valor pagado este mes en la deuda':€)
```

Comment: La resta de dos valores se hace con `-`. Los valores, si están en un diccionarios, se acceden mediante la clave del diccionario, que en este caso es el nombre de la persona: `deudas["Nombre de la persona"]` eso te da el valor allí almacenado. Restas la cantidad necesaria y lo almacenas de nuevo en el mismo sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Solo modifica el valor del diccionario correspondiente al deudor. Por ejemplo:

```
deudas = dict()
deudas['Alfonso'] = float(input('Digite o valor devedor a  "Fafa":€ valor deuda: ' ))
print(deudas)
abono = float(input('Ingrese el valor pagado este mes en la deuda: '))
deudas['Alfonso'] = deudas['Alfonso'] - abono
print(deudas)
```

#### Resultados:

Deuda input

```
5000
```

Abono input:

```
3000
```

Output:

```
2000
```

Comment: Genial! 
Ahora la otra duda es : Como guardar los valores sin que tengo q estar siempre ingresando valores o ejecutando el programa?

Comment: Me explico ?
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que cada vez que entres al programa aparezca solo el monto faltante de la deuda? Por ejemplo si un día lo abres y abonas $100 quieres que eso se guarde para la próxima vez que lo abras?